# How to Get Audio sample data from mp3 using NAudio

Tags: naudio

I have an mp3 file into one large array of audio samples.
I want the audio samples to be floats.

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm=NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(OFD.FileName));
```

so far I get the pcm stream and can play that back fine but I don't know how to read the raw data out of the stream.

Comment: Which sort of `raw data` are you after?  MP3 frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AudioFileReader`. This implements `ISampleProvider` so the `Read` method allows you to read directly into a float array of samples.

Alternatively use the `ToSampleProvider` method after your `Mp3FileReader`. You don't need to use `WaveFormatConversionStream`, since `Mp3FileReader` (and `AudioFileReader`) already decompress the MP3 frames.

Comment: thanks Mark this worked as I wanted. Is there somewhere I can get more documentation on NAudio? The actual code I used was
                NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader afRdr = new AudioFileReader(OFD.FileName);
                float[] flBuffer = new float[2000];
                int bytesRead = afRdr.Read(flBuffer, 0, 2000);

Comment: have a look on the Documentation tab of the CodePlex site. It links to lots of articles on my blog. There's also a Pluralsight course I made recently if you're a subscriber. I'm hoping to write more documentation, but NAudio is just a spare time project, so progress can be slow at times.

Comment: I have got data now but how do I determine the length of the float buffer and what about when there are two channels

Comment: @MarkHeath Could you please let me know how we could determine the buffer size to read?